# Online parser tags different to local MaxentTagger tags

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm running the MaxentTagger directly like this:

```
private void test() {
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(modelsdir + "wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
    String input = "Someone will trip over that cable.";
    System.out.println(tagger.tagString(input));
}
```

And getting the following output:

> Someone_NN will_NN trip_NN over_IN that_DT cable_NN ._.

But when using the online parser I get this output:

> Your query
>
> > *Someone will trip over that cable.*
>
> Tagging
>
> > Someone/NN will/MD trip/VB over/RP that/DT cable/NN ./.

I tried using different models:

```
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(models + "english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
```

> Someone_NN will_MD trip_NN over_IN that_DT cable_NN ._.

but I cant seem to get the same results as the online version.

Why am I getting different tags for words when using the MaxentTagger in comparison to the online version?

Should I be using parameters when initializing the MaxentTagger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "online parser" do you mean the CoreNLP demo or the Stanford Parser demo? The latter will assign part-of-speech tags from the parse tree of the sentence, which can be different than those assigned by the part-of-speech tagger.

Comment: I'm referring to the Stanford parser demo. I've reread the documentation and it seems the stanford parser applies tags based on the parse like you've just said, whereas the pos tagger uses the HMM model. I've managed to get the same output as the online demo by using the pipeline using only "tokenize,ssplit,parse" as properties.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct. But, FWIW, the tagger is a discriminative maxent sequence tagger, not an HMM.